# Estimating planar mass distribution

Tags: statics

I have a planar object whose center of mass is not at the geometric centroid, and I want to roughly estimate the magnitude of four hypothetical point masses that at the four corners that would result in the center of mass. In summary, I want to backsolve the center of mass equation with reasonable assumptions. I currently have 2 equations for the center of mass in the x and y direction, but I need two more equations to be able to solve for all four.

Comment: can you split the surface into triangles, rectangles ... ? otherwise the answer here is perfect.

Comment: I can, but the center of mass is changing with time due to internal motion, so I would need to appropriately bias the smaller geometric objects with the motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say the off-center of center of mass from geometrical centroid is dx and dy, and total mass is M.

We assume the masses from top left counting clockwise m1,m2,m3,m4,located with their CGs equally located on four corner of a vertical rectangular. First let's assume the object is symmetrical, with b as the base of the rectangle and a as its vertical long side.

so we have $$\bar{x} =\frac {m1\times a/2 + m2\times a/2 +m3\times a/2 +m4\times a/2}{M} $$ and

$$\bar {y}= \frac {m1\times b/2 + m2\times b/2 +m3\times b/2 +m4\times b/2}{M}   $$

now we back calculate dx and dy into the above EQs to figure the difference in mass of individual parts.

We observe that if we add  a very small differential amount dm1 to m1 the center of gravity will move up and left away from center of geometry by a factor of

$$ dx=\space  \thicksim \frac{dm1\times a/2} {M+dm1}\space and\space \space dy =\space\thicksim \frac{ dm1\times b/2}{M+dm1}  $$
This rough approximation should give us intuition to figure out the discrepancy in mass or if we have an indication about the geometry we can set up the differential discrepancy as Dx for that.

Comment: I think I understand the idea of observing the incremental change in the center of mass. However, I'm confused by "back calculate dx and dy into the above EQs". I thought dx = x_bar and dy = y_bar.

Comment: yes, what we do we are figuring out how much mass density or additional mass has caused this dx and dy. imagine you have used 4 plates of identical size to put next to each other to create your rectangular. But the one on top left is a bit thicker or made of a heavier alloy. this would enable you to figure that out.